# Spock error groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: when one method calls another

Tags: grails, testing, groovy, spock

When running a unit test I get an error about spoc closure failing when the method being tested calls another method inside of the object under test.

The error is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mypackage.RuleRunnerServiceSpec$__spock_feature_0_9_closure12.doCall() is applicable for argument types: ([B, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...], ...]
Possible solutions: call(), doCall(java.io.InputStream), findAll()
    at com.mypackage.RuleRunnerService.loadRulesFromS3(RuleRunnerService.groovy:132)
    at com.mypackage.RuleRunnerServiceSpec.should load from s3(RuleRunnerServiceSpec.groovy:272)
```

The test is:

```
void "should load from s3"(){

        given:
            RuleRunnerService ruleService = RuleRunnerService.instance
            ruleService.grailsApplication = [
                    config: [
                            alert: [
                                    engine: [s3 : [bucketName: 'bucket']]
                            ]
                    ]
            ]
            def s3wrapper = mockFor(S3Wrapper, true)

            s3wrapper.demand.asBoolean(0..999) { -> true }
            s3wrapper.demand.getS3ObjectToInputStream(0..999){
               InputStream stream -> new FileInputStream('test/resources/samples-drl/samplefile.drl')
            }

            ruleService.s3 = s3wrapper.createMock()
        when:
            ruleService.loadRulesFromS3('test')
        then:
            ruleService.hasRulePackageByName('test')
```

The method being tested is:

```
void loadRulesFromS3(String organizationId){

        String bucketName = grailsApplication.config.alert.engine.s3.bucketName


        S3Wrapper s3 = getS3Wrapper()
        InputStream newRules = s3.getS3ObjectToInputStream(bucketName, organizationId)

        loadRulesFromString(organizationId, [newRules.text])
    }
```

The call exits with the error above on the loadRulesFromString(...) call. Is there some setup required to allow for internal method calls in a Spock test?

Comment: you should post your 's3wrapper', you are not using a mock from spock

Answer (score 0):

We can't see the rest of the context around your test, but perhaps something like this:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
@TestFor(RuleRunnerService)
class RuleRunnerServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def "shouldLoadFromS3"() {
        given:
            grailsApplication.config.alert.engine.s3.bucketName = 'bucket'
            def s3WrapperMock = mockFor(S3Wrapper, true)
            s3WrapperMock.demand.with {
                asBoolean(0..99) { -> true }
                getS3ObjectToInputStream(0..999) { InputStream stream -> 
                    new FileInputStream('test/resources/samples-drl/samplefile.drl')
                }
            }
            service.s3 = s3WrapperMock.createMock()
        when:
            service.loadRulesFromS3('test')
        then:
            service.hasRulePackageByName('test')
    }
}
```

or something close to that (barring typos). I use Groovy mocks all the time in Spock Specifications.

Ideally the unit test for loadRulesFromS3 leaves that method as the only 'variable' in play in your test. Using hasRulePackageByName (which I assume is another method in the service) to determine the validity of loadRulesFromS3 is technically introducing another variable to your test. This test of loadRulesFromS3 could fail if there is an error in the hasRulePackageByName method. Whether that risk is consequential is up to you.